# Autoincrement MySQL table conditional on other column values

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the following structure:

```
ID  LEVEL  MOVE NUMBER  VALUE
1     1         1        123
1     1         2        345
```

I am recording the variable "value" with javascript and sending it to the database via PHP. What I need to do is build an SQL query to update the table by **autoincrementing the column "move number"**. However, this should occur **conditional on the columns values "ID" and "Level"**. This means that if a player with ID=2 plays level 1, the database should update as:

```
ID  LEVEL  MOVE NUMBER  VALUE
1     1         1        123
1     1         2        456
2     1         1        789
```

The same goes for the variable level. In the end, say we have a total of 3 players, two levels and 2 moves, the database should look like:

```
ID  LEVEL  MOVE NUMBER  VALUE
1     1         1        123
1     1         2        456
2     1         1        789
3     1         1        012
1     2         1        345
2     1         2        678
...
```

Grouping by either id or level is not important in this case. The important thing is that each move is recorded sequentially together with its value. As I am not so much familiar with SQL syntax, I am unsure how to achieve this

Comment: So basically the move will increase when ID and level (both) are repeated?

Comment: You can do this in MyISAM using a secondary key auto increment. There's no automatic method in InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. "MOVE NUMBER" should be one higher every time you insert a new move for a certain player "ID" and "Level". Calling this "autoincrementing" is somewhat misleading, because MySQL already has an [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), which is something different.

Let's first get the last "MOVE NUMBER" for a "ID" = 1 and "Level" = 1:

```
SELECT MAX(`MOVE NUMBER`) FROM GameScore WHERE ID = 1 AND Level = 1;
```

For the last results in your question this should return 2. However, this could return NULL, so we do:

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(`MOVE NUMBER`), 0) FROM GameScore WHERE ID = 1 AND Level = 1;
```

then it will return 0.

Now all we need to do is insert a new "VALUE", for instance 463. This goes like this:

```
INSERT INTO GameScore (ID, 
                       LEVEL, 
                       `MOVE NUMBER`, 
                       VALUE)
SELECT 1,
       1,
       IFNULL(MAX(`MOVE NUMBER`), 0) + 1, 
       463 
FROM GameScore 
WHERE ID = 1 AND 
      Level = 1;
```

Please note that queries are untested, they are just given as examples.